# what is the default global timeout for an Ajax request in Prototype?

Tags: javascript, ajax, timeout, prototypejs

I cannot find how can I attach an timeout [option](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/ajax/options) to the Ajax prototype call or what is the default value for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be specific timeout functionality in Prototype yet. It seems to be definitely in the works, see [**Prototype Ticket #220**](https://prototype.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8886/tickets/220). I'm guessing it is using whatever browser-wide global timeout there is for XMLHTTPRequests.

[**JQuery**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) seems to have this built in.

Comment: I added a link to a Prototype ticket. One person has a fork there that seems to implement timeouts.

Comment: the global value is 0, meaning it will go on until will reach network stack's time-out value. src: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc304105(VS.85).aspx